# gcloud preview app run: "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

When running gcloud preview app run from Google Compute Engine, running Ubuntu Trust 14.04 image, I get the following error:
(Note: I fetched the complete gcloud SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)

```
$ gcloud  preview app run appengine-modules-guestbook/src/main/webapp 
Java module found in [/home/yaraju_gmail_com/appengine-modules-sample-java/appengine-modules-guestbook/src/main/webapp]
INFO: Skipping SDK update check.
INFO: Starting API server at: http://localhost:46920
INFO: Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO: Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
Exception in thread Instance Adjustment:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1492, in _loop_adjusting_instances
    self._adjust_instances()
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1469, in _adjust_instances
    self._add_instance(permit_warmup=True)
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1354, in _add_instance
    if not inst.start():
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/instance.py", line 274, in start
    self._runtime_proxy.start()
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/http_runtime.py", line 270, in start
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/yaraju_gmail_com/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/safe_subprocess.py", line 132, in start_process_file
    stderr=stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing one of the dependencies.
Ensure that you have run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
gcloud components update gae-java
```